# Filter function in jquery with relevant value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the following filter funtion,

```
$.each(contacts,function(i,contact){                

            var keyword = (contact.dept+';'+contact.name+';'+contact.location+';'+contact.extn).toLowerCase();                

            if( keyword.indexOf(newSearchValue) != -1){
                newdata.push(contact);                
            }                
        });
```

Its works fine. It filters by ascending order by default. But i need exactly  what i am trying to search should come on top and the rest below. How can i get this result?

Comment: Can you post your code with some attempts or do you have any ideas?

Comment: Might I have misunderstood your question (see my answer below)? Do you mean that your results should be sorted by some kind of "matching quality"? I. e. those search results *matching best* should be listed first? But what does "matching best" mean then? As you are not using regular expressions it cannot be the matched length for example.

Comment: If i search  for a "xxx" but i am getting "yzxxx" i know it has got the same alphabet but i need what i am trying to search should come on top and the rest below.

Answer (score 2):

After created the array of `newdata`. you need to sort array like this

```
$.each(contacts, function(i, contact) {
  var keyword = (contact.dept + ';' + contact.name + ';' + contact.location + ';' + contact.extn).toLowerCase();

  if (keyword.indexOf(newSearchValue) != -1) {
    newdata.push(contact);
  }
});

newdata =newdata.sort(function(a, b){
return b.indexOf(newSearchValue) - a.indexOf(newSearchValue);
})
```

**Example**

**Updated**

```js
var newdata = [{  "id": "86",  "name": "fgdf",  "password": "",  "dept": "test",  "extn": "534534",  "mobile_no": "97767867677",  "location": "xxxx",  "email": "xxxx@gmail.commn",  "type": "0",  "dept_id": "1",
  "created_on": "2017-06-30 11:19:03",  "loc_id": "3"}, {  "id": "85",
  "name": "new",  "password": "",  "dept": "test1",  "extn": "565",
  "mobile_no": "4357347853945",  "location": "yyyyy",  "email": "test@gmail.com",  "type": "0",  "dept_id": "3",  "created_on": "2017-06-30 11:19:03",  "loc_id": "3"}]
  
var newSearchValue = 'h';//change the as your wish

newdata = newdata.sort(function(a, b) {
   var a1 = (a.dept + ';' + a.name + ';' + a.location + ';' + a.extn).toLowerCase()
      var b1 = (b.dept + ';' + b.name + ';' + b.location + ';' + a.extn).toLowerCase()
  return b1.indexOf(newSearchValue) - a1.indexOf(newSearchValue);
})

console.log(newdata)
```

Comment: +1 for adding a working example! Although this is something the OP should have done in the first place. Your example is different to your actual solution, presented above, as you are sorting the *whole* contacts array in your code snippet and only the *results* in the first mentioned solution.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @prasad. But its not working bcz the newdata is json object. It throws an indexOf is not a function error.

Comment: newdata = [{"id":"86","name":"fgdf","password":"","dept":"test","extn":"534534","mobile_no":"97767867677","location":"xxxx","email":"xxxx@gmail.commn","type":"0","dept_id":"1","created_on":"2017-06-30 11:19:03","loc_id":"3"},{"id":"85","name":"new","password":"","dept":"test1","extn":"565","mobile_no":"4357347853945","location":"yyyyy","email":"test@gmail.comm","type":"0","dept_id":"3","created_on":"2017-06-30 11:19:03","loc_id":"3"}]

Comment: @Renu try with updated one.And change the `newsearchvalue` as your wish

Answer (score 0):

It is a question of how you set up your `newdata` array:

```
var newdata=['newSearchValue'];
// then put your code snippet here
```

This way your results array starts off with the search expression itself on top with the actual search results following that.